# Update my app on the Play Store

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have an application (version 1.0 ) on the Play Store and now I want to update it to version 2.0 using the signature certificate.
The problem is that I don't know the certificate's alias.
I have never encountered a problem like this before.

What can I do to find it or to update the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the `keytool` binary from the JDK in your `PATH` and execute the following command

```
$ keytool -list -keystore your.keystore
Enter keystore password:

*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************
* The integrity of the information stored in your keystore  *
* has NOT been verified!  In order to verify its integrity, *
* you must provide your keystore password.                  *
*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

[YOUR ALIAS], Jan 11, 2015, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 11:7B:2A:22:39:5F:D9:....
```

Note on the second to last line `[YOUR ALIAS]` should print the alias of the key inside the keystore.